# Custom validation for Phone number in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, custom-validation

I have created the custom validation method to validate telephone number to accept only **numbers** and **(-** symbols. It's working when I tried with JavaScript in HTML page but not working when applied to **Magneto 2.3.3-p1**.

For this I have tried the below code to **rules.js** from **/root/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation**.

```
 'phone_number_checkout': [
            function (value) {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^[0-9-]/.test(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please enter a valid phone number. For example 123-(456)-(7890) or 123-456-7890 or 1234567890.')
        ]
```

and validation rule added to layout **checkout_index_index.xml** file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                                                                        <item name="phone_number_checkout" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item> 
                                                                
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Is my validation rule is correct? If it's wrong procedure please guide me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you Try with LayoutProcessor ? for Reference you can look into this file
Magecomp\Generalext\Block\Checkout\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved by adding below validation rule to **rules.js** file from **root/html/app/design/XXX/XXX/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/**

```
'phone_number_client': [            
            function (value){
                 return value.match(/^([0-9\(\)\/\\-]*)$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123)456-(7890) or 123-456-7890.')
        ]
```

The above validation will allow only numbers, hyphens(-) and brackets(()).